# Capturar requisição SOAP

Tags: c#, soap

Gostaria de efetuar o log de todas as requisições soap exatamente como chegaram em meu servidor. Há uma forma de isto ser efetuado via c#?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Services (ASMX) to WCF?

Comment: Nós usamos ASMX para estes webservices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei este link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

No webmethod ficaria assim:

```
[WebMethod]
[TraceExtensionAttribute]
public Type MethodName()
```

Resolveu meu problema, pois não achei uma opção no tracing que armazenasse o xml completo da requisição.

Grato a todos que me ajudaram.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é habilitar o tracing da sua aplicação. Adicione no arquivo `.config` do seu Web Service o seguinte:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
            <listeners>
                <add name="AsmxTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="local.log" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="Verbose"  />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb885203%28v=vs.100%29).

Ainda, é possível utilizar injeção de dependência para interceptar as chamadas ao Web Service. Isto pode ser feito através da geração de um proxy da camada de acesso. [A explicação está aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20150812225753/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dhrubach/archive/2008/10/20/8623711.aspx).

Comment: Mas o xml da requisição não vem no caso do tracing certo? Gostaria do xml completo para meu cliente verificar que quem está chamando erroneamente o webservice é ele.

Comment: É pra vir sim. O *tracing* inclui informações de serialização e desserialização.